# How to calculate the number of packets sent to or forwarded by a node in RPL protocol of ContikiOS?

Tags: contiki

In RPL for selecting the best parent with the trust model In order to select a trusted parent, direct and indirect trust must be calculated. For direct trust computation, the number of packets sent to node A by node B and the number of packets forwarded by node A on behalf of node B must be counted and I have trouble in determining the number of forwarded packets. Any help will be useful for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the values of `uip_stat.ip.sent` and `uip_stat.ip.forwarded`. Make sure to enable uIP statistics (`#define UIP_CONF_STATISTICS 1`).